# VBA PowerPoint - Go back to the slide I came from

Tags: vba, button, controls, slide, powerpoint

How would I accomplish this? Because I'm constantly adding and deleting the slides, I need the code to KNOW what slide I came from and not just go to a set slide.

Comment: What do you mean by `Go back to the slide I came from`. Are you moving via code, or do you mean each time you manullay delete or insert slides you want to return to the previously selected slide? What if you delete the previous slide in a multi-slide delete?

Comment: I figured it out, but I sense limitation coming with that code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide(SlideShowWindows(1).View.LastSlideViewed.SlideIndex)
```

Comment: This is much simpler than what I was using, LOL!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. With some help from browsing the web and a bit of thinking, I came up with this:

For storing the current slide number except the slides that requires you to go back to another slide, I made a module with:

```
Public CurrentSlide As Long, PreviousSlide As Long

Public Sub GoToPreviousSlide()
SlideShowWindows(1).View.GoToSlide (PreviousSlide)
End Sub

Public Sub StoreCurrentSlide()
CurrentSlide = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
If CurrentSlide <> 14 Then
'Execute only if the current slide is not a slide that uses this function (because if you store the current slide while in a slide that requires you to go back to another slide, it will overwrite the PurrentSlide value and render this useless). Add more slide numbers to the If statement as you need them.
PreviousSlide = CurrentSlide
Call GoToPreviousSlide
End If
End Sub
```

Of course I'd have to make sure that I call StoreCurrentSlide every time the slide changes, I made another module to automatically execute this:

```
Public Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
StoreCurrentSlide
End Sub
```

Now I can use a button anywhere and go back to the previous slide by using:

```
Private Sub OK_Click()
GoToPreviousSlide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a button anyhow, why not use PPT's action settings; assign an action setting of Previously Viewed Slide.  Clicking the button will take the viewer back to whatever slide they were viewing immediately prior to the current slide.

No VBA required.

Comment: I have bad experience with the action settings, but that was back in Office 2003. It would to go a slide BEFORE itself, not the slide I came from. Like say if I jump from slide 2 to 5 and want to go back, the action setting would take me to 4.

Comment: Better late than never, I suppose: you're describing what happens with a Previous Slide action, not Previously Viewed Slide. But you've solved it differently, so no matter.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft 365] Within a presentation (slide show), type the number and press Enter. When editing the slides, I use this VBA macro kept in a file "Macros.pptm":

```
Sub GoToSlide()
Dim currNum As Integer, newNum As Integer, a As String
currNum = _ 
CInt(Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex)
a = InputBox("Current slide [" & currNum & "]:" & _ 
vbCrLf & _"Go to slide number:", _
"GoToSlide", currNum)
If (a <> "") Then
newNum = CInt(a)
Application.ActiveWindow.View.GoToSlide (newNum)
End If
End Sub
```

I have assigned this macro as a new command to the quick access ribbon. When I edit a deck I have to open the file "Macro.pptm" too in order to find the macro.
The macro displays the current slide number and prompts for the desired slide number, then goes there (unless user presses ESC).